# Talend: Merge CSV files which has dynamic column

Tags: file, talend

I want to merge two CSV files. The problem that I am facing is one of the two CSV files has dynamic column.

e.g.

The first CSV file has two column. A and G. Column G has comma separated values.

```
A | G       |<-Column Names
--|---------|
A1| G1,G2,G3| <-Row
A2| G2,G5,G6|<-Row
```

[image: MainCSv]

The second CSV file has dynamic columns. But it will alwas have the column A(uid). e.g.

```
A | C1    |C2       |Othercolumns|<-Column Names
--|-------|---------|------------|
A1|C1Value|C2Value  |            |<-Row
A2|C1Value| C2Value |            |<-Row
```

[image: Lookup CSV]

I want to merge these two files So the output will be:

```
A |G          | C1    |C2       |Othercolumns|<-Column Names
--|-----------|-------|---------|------------|
A1| G1,G2,G3  |C1Value|C2Value  |            |<-Row
A2| G2,G5,G6  |C1Value| C2Value |            |<-Row
```

[image]

I can't use tmap because the second file has dynamic columns.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your A column is static you can still use a tMap to do this.

A simple job might look like this:

[image: Job layout]

First of all, set the schema for your second CSV to have 2 columns: A (string type) and RemainingCols (dynamic type).

[image: CSV2 schema]

And your first CSV should have a schema like this:

[image: CSV1 schema]

Then just join your two data sources with a tMap as normal:

[image: tMap configuration to join the 2 schemas]

Comment: I did this. But it is only fetching the column G.

Comment: I've added some example screenshots. Does that help at all? If not can you show us what you've done by editing your question?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. i have added the screenshots. i am doing the exact same thing.

Comment: What does your output look like? I assume you have different delimiters for CSV1? Obviously if you want to keep all of G as a delimited values column then the delimiter needs to be different in G than between G and A.

Comment: The delimiters are different in both the CSVs. The uid column is the 6th column in CSV2. Do you thing that can be the problem? I am only getting the columns(A and G) from CSV1. The dynamic columns from CSv2 are missing from output file.

Comment: In CSV1 the delimiter between columns(A and G) is ";" and between values of G is "~".

Comment: Nope, that seems fine. As always, the best bet to debug odd behaviour is to throw tLogRows at everything. Drop tLogRows between your input CSVs and the tMap and then again between the tMap and the output CSV.

Comment: Is this working for you? Even when the column A is not the first column?

Comment: Your matching column in the second CSV must be the first one (or at least not after a dynamic group of columns) as the dynamic column will simply pick up all of the remaining columns (it must be last in the schema). If this is not the case then you need to make the whole thing dynamic and parse out and extract the A column (or whatever you're using to match) using a tJavaRow component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Talend Open Studio then the following solution could be good:

- Use a tFileInputFullRow component to read your files.
- With a tJavaRow split the inputrows into 2 column: A1 / Rest
- Run this line into a tMap, do the join.
- Use tJavaRow to create the lines for the output.